0-connective objects in an $\infty$-topos
I am trying to understand Marc Hoyois's proof of the Van Kampen theorem in an $\infty$-topos given as Lemma 6 in :
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/Hoyois_PlusConstruction.pdf
In the course of the proof, he reduces to the case where an object $X$ in the $\infty$-topos is $1$-connective. This means that both the map $X\to 1$ and the diagonal $X\to X\times X$ are effective epimorphisms. He then deduces: since $X$ is in particular $0$-connective, we may assume it has a global section $1\to X$.
I don't understand this argument. It seems to me that a $0$-connective object in an $\infty$-topos need not have a global section. For instance, in the $\infty$-topos $PSh(I)$ of presheaves on the cospan category $I=\bullet \to \bullet \leftarrow \bullet$ the object $\Delta^0 \xrightarrow{i_1} \Delta^0\sqcup \Delta^0 \xleftarrow{i_2} \Delta^0$ is $0$-connective, yet doesn't have a global section.
I must have missed something, but I feel a bit stuck at the moment. Thank you for your help.

Not an answer, but it seems to me that $0$-connective objects do not necessarily have global sections unless we assume some sort of ''propositional axiom of choice'' in our $\infty$-topos (namely, Prop. 6.5.1.12 in HTT says that an object is $0$-connective iff its $(-1)$-truncation is a terminal object), or at least we need the terminal object to have left-lifting against effective epis with $(-1)$-truncated targets. Given that this fails for general $1$-topoi, I would be surprised if it actually holds for $\infty$-topoi in general, so I am interested in an answer to this question as well.

Thinking about this again, I thought that maybe he means the following: if we replace the topos $\mathcal{E}$ by the slice $\mathcal{E}{/X}$, the object $"X"$ (which is really $\pi_2 : X\times X \to X$) now has a global section, namely the diagonal $X \to X\times X$. This has nothing to do with $X\to 1$ being an effective epimorphism. However, I would suspect that $X\to 1$ being effective epi implies a particular property of the etale geometric morphism $\mathcal{E}{/X} \to \mathcal{E}$ that lets Marc argue this way... But it is still unclear to me.

It is correct that a $0$-connective object need not have a global section, and as you describe in your comment the intended reasoning was indeed to pass to the slice topos over $X$ (Marc has confirmed this). The key ingredient you need to input is that for an effective epimorphism $f\colon X \to Y$ in an $\infty$-topos $\mathcal{X}$, the pullback functor $f^*\colon \mathcal{X}_{/Y} \to \mathcal{X}_{/X}$ is conservative, i.e. equivalences can be checked after pulling back along an effective epimorphism (see Lemma 6.2.3.16 in HTT). It then follows that also the desired pushout square can be checked after pulling back along an effective epimorphism.
Here's also Marc's response to this question: ''Any $0$-connective object locally has a global section, so to check any local statement (such as some square being a pushout in this case) you can assume that it actually has a global section.''

Many thanks, that settles it !
